# How do I sorting an array using this way only ...?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an (one dimension array) using the following way only.
The way is :

We have this array :

Index : 0-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6

Values: 10----5-----6-----11----2-----5-----1

2- Create a new array :
 Collapse | Copy Code
int []Sorting =new int [7]

3- now we want to find min number from the source array the put it in index 0 in the new array "Sorting" then make the min number in source array = 0 , like that :
this is the source array after one loop :

Index : 0-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6

Values: 10----5-----6-----11----2-----5-----0

this is the sorted array :

Index : 0-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6

Values: 1----null---null--null--null--null--null

4- We must loop this step to make "Sorting"array sorted, like this :

Index : 0-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6

Values: 1-----2-----5-----5----6-----10-----11

==========================================================================
this is my code but I can't continue more than that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   

int [] RandomArray = new int [8];
    //Inserting
    for(int i=0;i<RandomArray.length;i++)
    {

String element= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert any number "+ (i+1));
RandomArray [i]=Integer.parseInt(element);


    }

    int []SortedArray=new int [8];
    for(int s=0; s< RandomArray.length;s++)
    {


    for(int d=0;d<RandomArray.length;d++)
    {



            if (s==d || RandomArray[s]==0) 
        {


        }
        else



        {


            int x ;

            if (RandomArray[s]<RandomArray[d])

            {

                //SortedArray[s] = RandomArray[s];
                SortedArray[s] = RandomArray[s];
                x=s;

            }else

            {
                SortedArray[s] =    RandomArray[d];
                x=d;
            }

            RandomArray[x]=0;


        }//end first else
    }//end second for


    }//end first for

}
```

Comment: ok.. what is the difference between steps 3 and 4?. Why do you have null in step 3?. If its sorting that you want why not just use Arrays.sort()?

Comment: This is a great site for you to come and ask specific questions, such as "how to fix the error that I'm getting on this line...", but your question is not really a question at all but a homework dump, and risks getting this question closed. To prevent this from happening, I urge you to show the fruits of your efforts, to ask specific and answerable questions about just where you're stuck, and to show your code. We'd love to help you with those, help you learn and finish the project yourself, but we don't want to finish your homework for you.

Comment: OK, what's the problem?

Comment: If you want us to do your sorting homework, then you are sort of ou of sort.

Comment: Ok my friend .. this is my code but I can't continue , please help me to sorting my array using my way only ,please :

Comment: If you want to learn an algorithm like this, write out the steps and your arrays with every change you make for an explicit example. Don't just start writing code before you understand the algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is like asking how to implement insertion sorting try the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] RandomArray = new int [5];
    for(int i=0;i<RandomArray.length;i++){
        String element= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert any number "+ (i+1));
        RandomArray [i]=Integer.parseInt(element);
    }
    int []SortedArray=new int [5];
    int sortArrayLength = 0;
    for(int d=0;d<RandomArray.length;d++) {
        int i = 0;
        int small = RandomArray[i];
        while(sortContains(small, SortedArray)){
            small = RandomArray[++i];
        }
        for(int k=0;k<RandomArray.length;k++){
            int temp = RandomArray[k];
            if(sortContains(temp,SortedArray)){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                if(temp < small){
                    small = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        SortedArray[sortArrayLength++] = small;
    }

    for(int k=0;k< SortedArray.length;k++){
        System.out.println(SortedArray[k]);
    }
}
private static boolean sortContains(int temp, int[] sortedArray) {
    boolean ret = false;
    if(sortedArray == null || sortedArray.length == 0)
        ret = false;
    else {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<sortedArray.length;i++)
            if(temp == sortedArray[i]){
                ret = true;
                break;
            }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: My friend this is work but not always . please run this code and try to put this values in random array :"1,2,3,4,5"
The sorted array will not be right.

Comment: @user3789924 : thanx for notifying that mistake :) edited code...

Comment: Thanks a lot this is that I want exactly.